# Deleting value of each input Javascript

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, attr

I have 3 inputs (autocomplete's of JqueryMobile).
Using this function:

```
$('.ui-input-clear').attr('onclick', 'delete_email();');
```

I add onclick event to each clear button, but what can I do for ONLY delete the input of the same button?

Example:

```
[<------INPUT------>]  [BUTTON] //If I click, the value of THIS input turns ""

[<------INPUT------>]  [BUTTON] //If I click, the value of THIS input turns ""

[<------INPUT------>]  [BUTTON] //If I click, the value of THIS input turns ""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not providing the code for `delete_email()`. Give all inputs unique `id`'s, then:

```
$('.ui-input-clear').click(function() {
  delete_email($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

And modify your delete function to take an id parameter, then use this id to identify the input that needs to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.ui-input-clear').click(function(){
   $(this).prev().find('input').val('');
});
});
```